# JQuery not selecting specific element after using .replaceWith() function to replace a <p> element with <input type=text>

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am creating a profile page for my app's users and i want to let the user change his personal information. My idea is  when the page loads, his personal information is displayed in rows inside a `<p>` tag. And then when he decides to edit his info, the `<p>` tag is replaced with a textbox and it's value is the text from the `<p>` tag.

Now the problem is, when i try to do anything with the textboxes JQuery doesn't seem to select them even if i had already assigned an id for the textboxes. 
**Note** no errors are shown in the console

I tried getting the textbox's id when i click it using this function.

```
$(window).click(function(e) {
        alert(e.target.id);
});
```

the id gets alerted but still, JQuery doesn't want to select the textboxes.

here's my code.

**html**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Epicurean Inc.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Contact-Form-Clean.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Footer-Basic.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.1.1/aos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Navigation-with-Button.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body id="profile">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md navigation-clean-button" data-aos="zoom-in-up" data-aos-duration="1000" id="profile-navbar">
        <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand pulse animated" href="index.php" id="homelink">Epicurean</a><button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div
                class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul><span class="navbar-text actions"> <a class="btn btn-light action-button" role="button" href="logout.php" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse" id="logoutbtn">Log Out</a></span></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <h1 data-aos="zoom-in-up" data-aos-duration="1000" id="profile-banner">Your Profile</h1>
    <div class="container" data-aos="zoom-in-up" data-aos-duration="1000" id="profile-container">
        <div id="heading">
            <h1 class="d-inline-block float-left icon ion-person" id="about">&nbsp;About Me</h1><i class="icon ion-edit d-inline-block" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse" id="edit" title="Edit"></i></div>
        <form action="updateprofile.php" method="POST">
            <div id="profie-content">
                <div class="profile-fields">
                    <p class="d-inline-block title">First name:&nbsp;</p>
                    <p id="er1"></p>
                    <p class="d-inline-block totext" id="item1">Paragraph</p><!--this is the p tag that gets replaced to textbox-->
                </div>
                <div class="profile-fields">
                    <p class="d-inline-block title">Last name:&nbsp;</p>
                    <p id="er2"></p>
                    <p class="d-inline-block totext" id="item2">Paragraph</p><!--this is the p tag that gets replaced to textbox-->
                </div>
                <div class="profile-fields">
                    <p class="d-inline-block title">Middle name:&nbsp;</p>
                    <p id="er3"></p>
                    <p class="d-inline-block totext" id="item3">Paragraph</p><!--this is the p tag that gets replaced to textbox-->
                </div>
                <div class="profile-fields">
                    <p class="d-inline-block title">Date of birth:&nbsp;</p>
                    <p id="er4"></p>
                    <p class="d-inline-block totext" id="item4">Paragraph</p><!--this is the p tag that gets replaced to textbox-->
                </div>
                <div class="profile-fields">
                    <p class="d-inline-block title">Email address:&nbsp;</p>
                    <p id="er5"></p>
                    <p class="d-inline-block totext" id="item5">Paragraph</p><!--this is the p tag that gets replaced to textbox-->
                </div>
                <div class="profile-fields">
                    <p class="d-inline-block title">Password:&nbsp;</p>
                    <p id="er6"></p>
                    <p class="d-inline-block totext" id="item6">Paragraph</p><!--this is the p tag that gets replaced to textbox-->
                </div>
                <div class="profile-fields">
                    <p class="d-inline-block title">Contact number:&nbsp;</p>
                    <p id="er7"></p>
                    <p class="d-inline-block totext" id="item7">Paragraph</p><!--this is the p tag that gets replaced to textbox-->
                </div>
                <div class="profile-fields">
                    <p class="d-inline-block title">Application status:&nbsp;</p>
                    <p class="d-inline-block" id="appstat">Paragraph</p>
                </div>
                <div id="link">
                    <a class="float-right links" href="#" id="resume">View resume</a>
                    <a class="d-block float-right links" href="#" id="assessment">View assesment</a>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-light action-button" type="submit" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse"
                    id="savebtn">Save changes</button>
                <button class="btn btn-light action-button" type="button" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse" id="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-basic">
        <footer>
            <div class="social"><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-instagram"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-snapchat"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i></a></div>
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            </ul>
            <p class="copyright">Epicurean Partners Exchange Inc. © 2017</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bs-animation.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.1.1/aos.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/profile.js"></script><!--my jquery file is imported-->
</body>

</html>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $("#edit").click(function() { //turns the fields into text boxes when edit button is clicked
        for (var i = 1; i < 8 ; i++) {//for loop for replacing <p> tags with textboxes  
            if (i == 4) {
                $("#item"+i).replaceWith("<input type='date' id='"+i+"' class='txtbox' min='1940-12-31' max='2003-12-31'>"); //value='"+ $("#item"+i).text() +"'>");
            } else if (i == 6) {
                $("#item"+i).replaceWith("<input type='password' id='"+i+"' class='txtbox' value='"+ $("#item"+i).text() +"'>");
            } else {
                $("#item"+i).replaceWith("<input type='text' id='"+i+"' class='txtbox' value='"+ $("#item"+i).text() +"'>");
            }
        }
        $("#savebtn").slideDown().removeAttr("hidden");
        $("#cancelbtn").slideDown().removeAttr("hidden");
    });
    $("#cancelbtn").click(function() { //reloads the page if user cancels
        location.reload();
    });

    $("#1").click(function() {//not working

        alert("textbox is clicked");

    });
});
```

Comment: Please share additional info.. What is the error you are facing and what you have tried already..

Comment: Oh, sorry i'll edit it.

Comment: Do you get any console log error?

Comment: No errors whatsoever.

Comment: Help me lol....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind an event on dynamically created element use
    `$(document).on(eventName, selector, function(){});`

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/881429/

Hope I answered the question.